# React Native: "Access denied" error when uploading a video to AWS Amplify

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am trying to upload a video to AWS S3 by using AWS Amplify in React native.

problem: when loading completed I get a blocking error!
axios-http-handler - Request failed with status code 403
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection
AccessDenied: Access Denied

expectation: video loading without errors

my code:

```
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify'
import { StoragePutOutput, StorageProvider, StoragePutConfig } from '@aws-amplify/storage'

interface fileUpload {
    filePath: string
    id: string
    onUploadProgress: (progressEvent: { loaded: number, total: number }) => void
    onErrorUpload: (text: string) => void
    onUploadConfirmed: () => void
  }

// method uploadFile
const uploadFile = (props: fileUpload, file: Blob): StoragePutOutput<StorageProvider> | undefined => {
    try {
      const extension = props.filePath.split('.').pop() ?? ''
      const fileName = `jobs/${props.id}_${Date.now()}.${extension}`
  
      const fileProps: StoragePutConfig<'AWSS3'> = {
        resumable: true,
        contentType: `video/${extension}`,
        tagging: `id=${props.id}`,
        progressCallback: props.onUploadProgress,
        completeCallback: props.onUploadConfirmed,
        errorCallback: (err) => {
          console.error('Unexpected error while uploading', err)
        },
        customPrefix: {
          public: ''
        }
      }
  
      const putRequest = Storage.put(fileName, file, fileProps)
  
      return putRequest
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error uploadFile', e)
      props.onErrorUpload(withTranslation('jobs_error_upload'))
    }
  }

//method cancel request when user decides to stop uploading the file
const cancelRequestUploadFile = (promise: Promise<Object>): void => {
  try {
    void Storage.cancel(promise, 'onPress cancel request')
  } catch (e: any) {
    console.log('error', e)
    if (Storage.isCancelError(e)) {
      console.log(e.message) // "my message for cancellation"
    }
  }
}

//bucket policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::{BUCKET_NAME}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post.your bucket policy?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra S3 bucket is private (Bucket and objects not public). 
Users that can read and write the bucket are logged id through Cognito Identity Provider!
I added the bucket policy in the comment above
IMPORTANT: The error is raised after the upload of the file to S3 (I can see the file on S3)

Answer (score 1):

Your IAM policy should contain the following permission:

```
{
  "Sid": "S3Bucket",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "s3:ListBucket"
   ],
   "Resource": [
     "arn:aws:s3:::{BUCKET_NAME}"
   ]
}
```